# I need to update the changed row in the grid using ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am new to jqGrid, I really need help.

After clicking on "submit" I want to update the row without reloading the page using Ajax. Tell what I need to write.

[image]

**My code**

I was able to update the data by updating the page, but I need it without an update

> View

```js
{
    //edit
    url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "TableDocument")',
    closeAfterEdit: true,
    height: 250,
    width: 400,
    afterSubmit: function(responce) {
        $("#jqg").jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
        return [true, responce.responseText];
    }
},
```

> Controller

```
    private static bool tuggel = false;
    private DataContext db = new DataContext();
    private Testing testing = new Testing();

    public TableDocumentController()
    {
        if (!tuggel)
        {
            testing.DataList();
            tuggel = true;
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public string GetData()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(db.DataBases);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public void Edit(DataBase data)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Entry(data).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to reload the listing grid on update event using ajax call.

Comment: @bindi.raval How it is make?

Comment: Use these steps, it will resolve your issue.https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/performing-crud-operation-using-jqgrid-in-Asp-Net-mvc/

Comment: @bindi.raval Thank you very much, acted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [reloadAfterSubmit option](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/#edit-grid-row) set to false

```
{
    //edit
    url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "TableDocument")',
    closeAfterEdit: true,
    reloadAfterSubmit : false,
    height: 250,
    width: 400,
    afterSubmit: function(responce) {
        $("#jqg").jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
        return [true, responce.responseText];
    }
},
```